# Home screen width Stretch

Tags: css

I am developing a website using wordpress, http://www.csde.epizy.com/, so I want to ensure that width of the content is stretched. What i mean is that: if you load the site (above link) and clearly observe - you'll notice that all the sections are within the whole frame. I want it to cover and be stretched (like this - https://jahnavi8.wixsite.com/website-5). 
I assume this is something that needs to be altered in style.css and it as something to do with page padding, any pointers will be of great help.

I am using 'Elementor' plugin and 'West' theme.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it.

Try adding the following codes in your stylesheet.

```
.container-fluid{
padding-left: 0 !important;
padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Or add these codes to prevent padding in any direction

```
.container-fluid{
padding: 0 !important;
}
```